# Conditional "With" binding on data-bind

Tags: html, knockout.js, data-binding, knockout-3.0

Using knockout JS, how can I apply a conditional `with` binding to HTML?

I have two observables, either one should be used based on a condition for the same html code. I want to do something like this:

if `some-condition`:

```
<div data-bind="with: observable1">
```

else:

```
<div data-bind="with: observable2">

      <!-- the below is common code -->             
      <label data-bind: "text: observable-property"></label>
      <!-- .... -->

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried refactoring your code, so this if logic is being done under hood of your model and you have one binding in html?

Comment: Question was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div data-bind="with: var1() ? var2 : var3">
  <div data-bind="text: a">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can bind an observable conditionally to the `with` binding like this.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nisarg0/287ypsg1/) for a demo.

Comment: Using this I get the error: 
_Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if: some-observable();_
Even though it is at the end, as suggested

Comment: Yup, it seems much simpler than that. See the updated answer. I have also attached a fiddle with a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use comment tags:

```
<!-- ko if: foo -->
<div data-bind="with: bar"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: foo -->
<div data-bind="with: baz"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is that the code written inside the `div` would have to be written twice.

Comment: True that :) But the original question wasn't really clear about whether the content of the `div` would be the same in both cases. And I had not thought of using a condition in the `with` binding. Much more elegant!